# Java GIS framework with custom shaped markers

Tags: java, api, gps, markers, gis

I need to find a open-source Java framework/library/api that would generate an map image with multiple coordinates markers. In particular I need to customize the shape of the markers (i.e. making the marker circle size bigger or smaller depending on external additional data). Moreover, it would be nice that the map would fit to the markers (so if I place markers only in Europe, the image would show Europe only, not the whole globe). Does any one know an Java API that has such functionality? I looked at things like geotools or jmapviewer but they seem to lack the features I require.